# how to add condition to complex select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 4 tables

```
1. course 
------------------------ 
CourseID   CourseNum    CourseName             

2. courseRequirements
------------------------
CourseID  ReqID                

3. semestercourses
------------------------
CourseID                

4. studentcoursecomplete
-----------------------
CourseID   StudentID
```

MY statement do the folowing

1-show the course name from table course where course.CourseID=semestercourses.CourseID
2-don't show the course that student complete "studentcoursecomplete"
3-don't show the course that have a requirement that student didn't finish 
4- show the course that have requirement that student finish

```
SELECT c.*, sc.* FROM semestercourses AS sc 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN course AS c 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr
NATURAL LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete   AS scc
WHERE 
sc.CourseID NOT IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete)
AND 
(cr.RequirementID IS NULL OR cr.RequirementID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM
studentcoursecomplete))
```

THE statement make it correctly ..
but how can i make it for a spicific Student
for example studentcoursecomplete.StudentID=1
!! how can i do that?

Comment: did you try "like" or equals in SQL

Comment: when i use this i get a wrong data that say "no data" .. so i must to put it in the correct place

Comment: couldnt you just add an extra clause to your where statement such as 'AND scc.StudentID = 1'

Comment: You are excluding courses that are in the studentcoursecomplete table and then looking for student_ids from studentcoursecomplete.  Wouldn't that exclude the rows you are trying to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
courseid
,coursenum
,coursename
FROM course 
WHERE
courseid not in (SELECT courseid from studentcoursecomplete where studentid =1)
and courseid in (SELECT courseid from courseRequirements where ReqID is not NULL)
and courseid in (SELECT courseid from semester courses)
```

Hopefully this works and I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: how can we make it so that SQL can prompt the user to provide studentID and using that value, we can use the studentID variable instead of specifying the hard coded (1) value. May be Gabriel want that.